# Bucket Sort with k unique elements

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Using Bucket Sort, sort `n` elements among which `k` elements are unique. Runtime should be `O(kn)`. `k` is based on the input and isn't known in advance. You cannot assume the elements are in a specific range, and the runtime cannot be based on the maximum element (it can be larger than `k`).

There are more efficient algorithms, but a `O(kn)` one is requested.

I think only very basic data structures are should be used (i.e. not hash maps etc.).

I'm not sure how to use the uniqueness in relation to buckets...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Runtime O(kn) assumes that time for appropriate bucket searching is O(k).

Such time together with O(1) per inserting of new bucket is provided with linked list.

> how to use the uniqueness in relation to buckets

k unique elements form k buckets (with single value per bucket)

Comment: Not sure I get it. Go through array, and for each element insert into its corresponding bucket (k buckets for k unique elements). But the order of the buckets itself isn't sorted.. so after O(kn) we have the unsorted buckets (i.e. list of unique elements). Now we need to sort them, no?

Comment: Linked list might be sorted by bucket value. But it is **not needed** for given run time. After bucketing traverse list, find the smallest value and output its content. Repeat for the next value etc

Comment: Finding smallest value each time out of k elements is O(k), and we do that O(k) times, so that means O(k^2), no?

Comment: Yes, and `k^2 <= k*n` does not violate run time